# Codimension of $J(\omega_1)$ in its bidual

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

I am reading the paper

G. A. Edgar, A long James space, in: *Measure Theory*, Oberwolfach 1979, Lectures Notes in Math. 794, Springer-Verlag (1980) pp. 31-37.

and I am pretty confused by the remarks after the proof of Proposition 3.

Is it clear that $J(\omega_1)$ is of codimension 1 in $J(\omega_1)^{** }$ (via the canonical map) in the same way as the (usual) James space $J$ is of codimension 1 in $J^{** }$?

Btw. I posted this question at MathStack but it has not been answered.

Comment: By now, math.stackexchange.com gets questions at such a rate that--even if I look there every day--I may miss questions of interest to me.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill is correct: $J(\omega_1)$ is not of codimension $1$ in its bidual.  The remarks after Proposition 3 say: (if $\eta$ is infinite) then $J(\eta)^{**}$ is isometric to $\widetilde{J}(\eta+1)$, and the set-theoretic inclusion is the canonical embedding.  The tilde on the $J$ means that we drop the requirement of continuity.  So we get a new dimension for each limit ordinal up to $\eta$.  Basically, while elements of $J(\eta)$ must be continuous, elements of the bidual $\widetilde{J}(\eta+1)$ need not be continuous, so we can have "jump" discontinuities at the limit ordinals.

Comment: This other question on the long James space might be of interest to you, too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69807/

Comment: Btw. is $J(\eta)$ isomorphic to $J(\xi)$ whenever $\omega\leq \xi, \eta<\omega_1$? I suspect not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access here to Edgar's article, but I very much doubt that he said that the long James space is quasi-reflexive!

You can get an explicit description and discussion of the second dual of the long James space in two papers from the mid 1980s:

Zhao, Jun Feng(PRC-WUHAN)
The transfinite basis of the bidual space of the long James space. 
Acta Math. Sci. (English Ed.) 5 (1985), no. 3, 295–301. 
46B10

MR0843290 (87k:46044) 
Zhao, Jun Feng
The ordering structure on Banach spaces. II. (Chinese. English summary) 
J. Wuhan Univ. Natur. Sci. Ed. 1985, no. 3, 11–18. 
46B20